# How can I mark methods created with `reify` with ^:export, so that the Closure compiler doesn't rename them?

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, google-closure

When creating JavaScript objects with `reify`, how can I mark the methods with `^:export` so that the Google Closure compiler doesn't rename them in advanced mode?

For example:

```
(reify
   Object
   (foo [this] ...)
   (bar [this] ...))
```

I've tried

```
(reify
   Object
   (^:export foo [this] ...)
   (^:export bar [this] ...))
```

but this doesn't seem to help, and the names still get changed with advanced optimizations.

If there isn't a way to do this, how can I construct a JavaScript object with methods, other than creating a plain `js-obj` and using `set!` to set functions to properties (where I'm not sure how to prevent advanced optimizations from breaking things either)?

Answer (score 6):

You have to provide `^:export` on your protocol methods as you will call them in JS, not methods from your reified object directly.

```
(ns example.core)

(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (^:export foo [this])

(defn ^:export create []
  (reify
    MyProtocol
    (foo [this] "bar")))
```

Then you can use it from JS:

```
var a = example.core.create();
var b = example.core.foo(a);
// b = "bar"
```

I tried it with the current [cljs.jar](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/releases/download/r3211/cljs.jar) and it emitted optimized JS with original `foo` name.